# How to analyze the returned result of cv::calibrateCamera?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, opencv3.0

According to the sample code given by opencv, the rms returned by calibrateCamera is the reprojection error, and the return of computeReprojectionErrors is also the reprojection error. I did an experiment and the two returned results are basically the same.
So why do you need to execute computeReprojectionErrors?
How to look at the relationship between rms and totalAvgErr?

```
rms = cv::calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePointsL, imageSize, cameraMatrixL, distcoeffsL, rvecsL, tvecsL, flags);

totalAvgErr = computeReprojectionErrors(objectPoints, imagePointsL, rvecsL, tvecsL, cameraMatrixL, distcoeffsL);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
static double computeReprojectionErrors( const vector<vector<Point3f> >& objectPoints,
                                         const vector<vector<Point2f> >& imagePoints,
                                         const vector<Mat>& rvecs, const vector<Mat>& tvecs,
                                         const Mat& cameraMatrix , const Mat& distCoeffs,
                                         vector<float>& perViewErrors, bool fisheye)
{
    vector<Point2f> imagePoints2;
    size_t totalPoints = 0;
    double totalErr = 0, err;
    perViewErrors.resize(objectPoints.size());

    for(size_t i = 0; i < objectPoints.size(); ++i )
    {
        if (fisheye)
        {
            fisheye::projectPoints(objectPoints[i], imagePoints2, rvecs[i], tvecs[i], cameraMatrix,
                                   distCoeffs);
        }
        else
        {
            projectPoints(objectPoints[i], rvecs[i], tvecs[i], cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, imagePoints2);
        }
        err = norm(imagePoints[i], imagePoints2, NORM_L2);

        size_t n = objectPoints[i].size();
        perViewErrors[i] = (float) std::sqrt(err*err/n);
        totalErr        += err*err;
        totalPoints     += n;
    }

    return std::sqrt(totalErr/totalPoints);
}
```

Comment: imho you can use `computeReprojectionErrors` with different data. With calibrateCamera you perform the calibration, so the intrinsics will be optimized with the provided data and the function returns the reprojection error that was achieved after optimizing with that data. With `computeReprojectionErrors` for example you can analyze that same intrinsics on an arbitrary validation/test set (captured with the same camera).

Comment: @Micka
 First of all, thank you very much for your answer. In simple terms, what you mean is to use the return value of computeReprojectionErrors to verify the return value of calibrateCamera. If the difference between the two is not big, it verifies that the calibration of calibrateCamera is correct, right?

Comment: You should use different data. And you will need to define some criteria about how that test data should look like.